# Unable to start MongoDB server on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, installation, ubuntu-20.04, systemctl

I'm installing the latest MongoDB on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa), and it's giving the below error. How can I fix it?

`sudo systemctl status mongod`

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-08-28 23:40:03 IST; 1min 43s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 10901 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
systemd[10901]: mongod.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
systemd[10901]: mongod.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/mongod: No such process
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service:11: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory >
```

Comment: Please visit this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111885/mongodb-4-2-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-18-04-after-reinstall-process-immediately-s) and follow solution

Answer (score 0):

Changing ownership of "/var/lib/mongodb" directory worked for me.
Command to change ownership:

> sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb

Comment: also check your creds

Comment: chown: cannot access '/var/lib/mongodb': No such file or directory

showing this error now